# how to append li in ul in boxwise?

Tags: jquery, css

Here am adding image for your reference.

I am having 3 ui in my container.Am using .sortable in jquery.**My problem is when am dragging li from ul2 to ul1 it should be arranged in two rows.**

Is it possible ? .

If I add more li to ui1 I should get the li in shown order.[image]

Comment: do you mean ul with ui?

Comment: no moving li from ui2 to ui1..dragging only li

Comment: please show your code and create a fiddle